# EF Core: How to calculate values for added column for existing rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I had a `NotMapped` property `CountUsed` in my entity.

For some reason (some UI controls I use) I switched this to a normal property, where I now update the value of `CountUsed` when I add a related child entity to this entity (Target<-Entries).

So long so good, but for the old rows in my database (where the value was previously calculated on the fly and not taken from the database table) I now would have no value inside those columns. Only if I would add a or remove a related Entry, it would calculated me a column value.

So my idea was, to add some code in the migration `Up()` method, to calculated the column values of the existing rows.

I have found an `UpdateData()` method:

```
  migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
        table: "Targets", 
        keyColumn: target_id, 
        keyValue: rowId, 
        column: "CountUsed", 
        value: calculatedCountUsedValue);
```

But having a look at the parameters, it looks not suitable for my case, or would I have to fetch my items first, iterate over them and call this method for every existing row?

Maybe there is some alternative, a better approach?

Comment: you can write your own raw sql and run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could now solve it with using the Sql() method to update the existing rows:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE Targets SET CountUsed = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Entries WHERE Entries.TargetId = Targets.TargetId)");
```